# HP DL 180 G6 installation problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hp-proliant, easy-install

I have a problem installing Windows 2003 Standart in a DL180 G6 using the Easy Set-Up CD provided by HP, Windows installation process return:

"The following value in the .SIF file used by setup is corrupt or missing, Value 1 on line 0 in section 'keyboard' setup cannot continue . to quit press F3"

I have tested with several keyboard always with the same results.
Know someone what is malfunctioning?

I'm using a USB stick to load the Easy Set-Up CD and the Windows image because the server has not optical devices and there is no PS2 port in this server.

PS: Disk controller not detected in a clasical windows installation.  (I prefer to avoid nLite)

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the front and rear USB ports for keyboard input? Do you have a USB CD/DVD drive to try with for the purposes of loading the Easy Setup disc and potentially the [current firmware DVD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884339&prodNameId=3884340&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-94560dcc34e845edbb13a26792)? Also, there's a chance that a [newer release of the Easy Setup CD](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=15351&prodSeriesId=3884339&prodNameId=3884340&swEnvOID=1005&swLang=8&mode=2&taskId=135&swItem=MTX-f6aac106f5f545efaa28bb49ff) than what you currently have is available for the server.

Comment: I agree with ewwhite, more than likely the making of your USB image did not go well, try re-creating the image otherwise get a USB CD/DVD drive for $40.00